# std::string with a custom allocator

Tags: c++, stl, allocator

So I'm currently in the process of writing a memory debugger and to do that I need stl container objects to use an untracked allocator.

I have std::string peppered throughout my entire codebase, so I typedef'd it to use my untracked allocator:

```
typedef std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, UntrackedAllocator<char>> String;
```

Now when I try to do this:

```
String str { "Some string" };
String copy = str;
```

I get this error:

```
/usr/local/include/c++/7.1.0/ext/alloc_traits.h:95:67: error: no matching function for call to 'UntrackedAllocator<char>::UntrackedAllocator(UntrackedAllocator<char>)' { return _Base_type::select_on_container_copy_construction(__a); }
```

This is what my Untracked Allocator looks like:

```
#pragma once

#define NOMINMAX
#undef max

template <typename T>
class UntrackedAllocator {
public:
    typedef T value_type;
    typedef value_type* pointer;
    typedef const value_type* const_pointer;
    typedef value_type& reference;
    typedef const value_type& const_reference;
    typedef std::size_t size_type;
    typedef std::ptrdiff_t difference_type;

public:
    template<typename U>
    struct rebind {
        typedef UntrackedAllocator<U> other;
    };

public:
    inline explicit UntrackedAllocator() {}
    inline ~UntrackedAllocator() {}
    inline explicit UntrackedAllocator(UntrackedAllocator const&) {}
    template<typename U>
    inline explicit UntrackedAllocator(UntrackedAllocator<U> const&) {}

    //    address
    inline pointer address(reference r) {
        return &r;
    }

    inline const_pointer address(const_reference r) {
        return &r;
    }

    //    memory allocation
    inline pointer allocate(size_type cnt,
        typename std::allocator<void>::const_pointer = 0) {
        T *ptr = (T*)malloc(cnt * sizeof(T));
        return ptr;
    }

    inline void deallocate(pointer p, size_type cnt) {
        free(p);
    }

    //   size
    inline size_type max_size() const {
        return std::numeric_limits<size_type>::max() / sizeof(T);
    }

    // construction/destruction
    inline void construct(pointer p, const T& t) {
        new(p) T(t);
    }

    inline void destroy(pointer p) {
        p->~T();
    }

    inline bool operator==(UntrackedAllocator const& a) { return this == &a; }
    inline bool operator!=(UntrackedAllocator const& a) { return !operator==(a); }
};
```

This is my first time working with custom allocators so I have no idea what's going on with it. It's incredibly annoyning that I can't do str1 = str2 if one of them uses a custom allocator.

Comment: Your relational operators are wrong. Allocators should compare equal whenever one can deallocate the other's allocation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The error message implies that you are using a copy constructor somewhere. The code you posted doesn't use a copy a constructor, though unless your subscript operator returns by value. Anyway, making the copy constructor explicit is rarely useful. Remove the `explicit` from the copy constructor and things should be fine.

Comment: @KerrekSB What do you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the declaration of the copy c'tors as `explicit`.

Changing the `UntrackedAllocator` copy c'tor to:

```
inline UntrackedAllocator(UntrackedAllocator const&) {}
```

Solves the compilation issue and everything works just fine:

```
int main() {
  String str { "13" };
  String copy = str;
  const char* cstr = str.c_str();
  int out = atoi(cstr);
}
```

This happens because the assignment operator of the `std::basic_string` that accepts `const std::basic_string &` requires an implicit copy construction of the allocator.