# How to pass a custom allocator to std::string in C++?

Tags: c++, string, allocator

I have `std::shared_ptr<std::string>`, and I'd like to measure the dynamic memory allocated by it at run time.
so simply put, I want to know:

1. the size of `std::shared_ptr<std::string>`.**`control_block`**
2. the portion which doesn't fit in small string optimization for `std::string`

I wrote a dummy allocator that just log the amount of RAM claimed, and intended to use it for both cases ([my example code](https://godbolt.org/z/y3tSaG)).
For case 1, I just passed my custom allocator as an argument to `std::allocate_shared`. 
and things just work, from the sample output I can see **48** bytes are used for creating the `control block`, among those **32** is used to hold the `string` and the rest **16** is probably split between the`ref_count` and `pointer to my custom allocator`

The issue happens when I try to pass the custom allocator to `std::string`, looking at the definition of `std::basic_string`, it has many constructors with allocator parameter, however ... I as far as I know `string` implementation usually does not hold a pointer to an allocator, so I don't know what could these functions possibly do?
[image]

`std::allocate_shared<std::string>(customStringAlloc,"confusedDev", customCharAlloc)` will build, but my own version of `allocate()` was never called...I managed to make it work by defining a new type `basic_string<char,char_traits<char>,CustomAllocator<char>>`. But I need a solution that returns `std::shared_prt<std::string>`...a different type won't cut it

Comment: The string has to store an instance of your allocator so you need to provide your allocator as a template parameter (as you've already figured out). If you don't want your allocator to be part of the type then you might need to look into polymorphic allocators. As for why `allocate` isn't invoked, I suspect `"confusedDev"` fits within SBO.

Comment: so these constructors with allocator as parameter simply ignores the user argument when they are provided?

Comment: I don't think I understand you. No constructor will just ignore a given allocator.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [std::string with a custom allocator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37502974/stdstring-with-a-custom-allocator)

Comment: @Kerndog73, what I meant is I can do `CustomAllocator<char> dummy;
    auto test = string("helloworld from confused dev", dummy);` following the [constructor def](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string). but my `CusomAllcator<char>` argument seems to be ignored

Comment: I am just confused about the all these types with `const Allocator& alloc` as param, for example the `std::vector` also exposes [this pattern](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector). `explicit vector( const Allocator& alloc );` or `explicit vector( size_type count, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );` but what can you really pass in as argument?

Comment: I'm surprised you don't get a compilation error for doing that. `CustomAllocator<char>` shouldn't be convertible to `std::allocator<char>`. The only way I can explain that is if you did something wierd like inheriting from `std::allocator<char>`. You have already discovered the solution to your problem, that is to pass the type of your allocator as a template parameter.

Comment: Do you understand what `Allocator` refers to in `basic_string(const Allocator &alloc)`?